# PyQGIS Dialog Plugin not resetting

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, sql, pyqt

I have written a PostGIS search plugin that works pretty well, except two things that I just cannot figure out a solution

1) When the dialog closes and then is reopened the previous query is still in the lineEdit and tableView. A tableView only seems to have clearSpans() however this is not clearing out the contents. I have tried .close(), .clear(), clearContents() none of which work or none are valid for a tableView.

I think the issue is I am loading the data from the database into a model via QSQLQueryModel.

2) When the user queries the database, selects a point the map moves to the location. If the user then opens the plugin again and queries the database again and selects a record from the tableView a point is added as a new memory layer, however it has the same XY coordinate as the first query.

I think the two problems are linked. Because number 1, the dialog isn't resetting properly, then the selected row from the table view gets confused.

I am so close and I think it will be a very useful plugin for the QGIS, so I hope someone can help. This might not be the best method to achieve this but having read the cookbook and the PyQGIS Programmers Guide it is the only way that may work

Thanks in advance

Full code can be seen on the github page here - https://github.com/tjmgis/PostGISSearch

This is the important code from the main python script

```
def cellClicked(self):
    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()

    index = self.dlg.tableView.currentIndex()

    rownumber = index.row()

    hmodel = self.dlg.tableView.horizontalHeader().model()
    for column in range(hmodel.columnCount()):
        if hmodel.headerData(column, Qt.Horizontal) == "x":
            xcolumn = column

        elif hmodel.headerData(column, Qt.Horizontal) == "y":
            ycolumn = column

        elif hmodel.headerData(column, Qt.Horizontal) == self.postgisdisplaycolumn:
            descriptioncolumn = column

    self.x = self.projectModel.index(rownumber, xcolumn).data()
    self.y = self.projectModel.index(rownumber, ycolumn).data()
    self.description = self.projectModel.index(rownumber, descriptioncolumn).data()

    self.pinLayer =  QgsVectorLayer(
          "Point?field=Description:string(120)&field=X_Coordinate:double&field=Y_Coordinate:double&index=yes",
          self.description,
          "memory")
    self.provider = self.pinLayer.dataProvider()
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(self.pinLayer)

    feature = QgsFeature()
    feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(self.x,self.y)))
    if QGis.QGIS_VERSION_INT > 10800:
        feature.setAttributes([self.description, self.x, self.y])
        self.pinLayer.startEditing()
        self.pinLayer.addFeature(feature, True)
        self.pinLayer.commitChanges()
    else:
        feature.setAttributeMap( {0 : QVariant(self.description),
            1 : QVariant(self.x),
            2 : QVariant(self.y)})
        self.provider.addFeatures([feature])
        self.pinLayer.updateExtents()
    #QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(), "Feature/field count", "%s / %s" % (str(self.provider.featureCount()), str(self.provider.fieldCount())))
    #self.pinLayer.reload()
    #self.pinLayer.setCacheImage(None)
    self.pinLayer.triggerRepaint()

    iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(QgsRectangle(self.x,self.y,self.x,self.y))
    iface.mapCanvas().zoomScale(10000)
    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()

    self.db.close()
    self.db.removeDatabase('QPSQL')

    self.dlg.close()


def addPostGISLayer(self, string):

    if len(string) > 4:
        uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
        # set host name, port, database name, username and password
        uri.setConnection(self.postgishost, self.postgisport, self.postgisdatabase, self.postgisusername, self.postgispassword)
        # set database schema, table name, geometry column and optionaly
        # subset (WHERE clause)
        if self.searchmethod == 'SQL':
            querystring = ("%" + string + "%")
            sql = "select %s.*, ST_X(%s) as x, ST_Y(%s) as y from %s.%s WHERE LOWER(%s) LIKE LOWER('%s') LIMIT 1000"%(self.postgistable, self.postgisgeomname, self.postgisgeomname, self.postgisschema, self.postgistable, self.postgissearchcolumn, querystring)

        elif self.searchmethod == 'FTS':
            sql = """SELECT %s.*, ST_X(%s) as x, ST_Y(%s) as y FROM %s.%s WHERE %s @@ plainto_tsquery('english', '%s') LIMIT 100"""%(self.postgistable, self.postgisgeomname, self.postgisgeomname, self.postgisschema, self.postgistable, self.postgissearchcolumn, string)

        else:
            iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Error", "Wrong search method declared in config file", level=QgsMessageBar.CRITICAL, duration=5)

        self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QPSQL')
        # check to see if it is valid
        if self.db.isValid():
            #iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Info", "Successfully connected to database", level=QgsMessageBar.INFO, duration=3)
            self.db.setHostName(uri.host())
            self.db.setDatabaseName(uri.database())
            self.db.setPort(int(uri.port()))
            self.db.setUserName(uri.username())
            self.db.setPassword(uri.password())
            # open (create) the connection
            if self.db.open():
                self.projectModel = QSqlQueryModel()
                self.projectModel.setQuery(sql,self.db)
                self.dlg.tableView.setModel(self.projectModel)
                self.dlg.tableView.resizeColumnsToContents()
                self.dlg.tableView.selectionModel().currentChanged.connect(self.cellClicked)
            else:
                iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Error", "Cannot open search on the database", level=QgsMessageBar.CRITICAL, duration=5)

        else:
            iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Error", "DB not valid", level=QgsMessageBar.CRITICAL, duration=5)

# run method that performs all the real work
def run(self):
    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    if result == 1:
        # do something useful (delete the line containing pass and
        # substitute with your code)
        pass
```